# How to implement parent-child windows and pass values from child to parent?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, popup, window, parent-child

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 2 application.

In one of my data entry forms, I have an "employer" field which has a "search" link next to it. When a user clicks on this link, another window is opened with a search form. The user uses the search form to search for the correct employer. A list of employers is shown to the user. Currently, the user has to then copy and paste the correct employer from the child window into the original window.

I want to implement it so that each employer search result in the child window is a hyperlink. The user would then click on the correct employer and then the correct employer value would be populated in the original parent window employer field.

How would I go about implementing this in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Comment: If this is really what you want to do, it's a javascript question - involves holding a reference to the new window in the old one, if you retag it then you may get an answer. I would question the usability of the whole approach though; you can get in a mess so easily by switching windows.

Comment: Thanks for the comment pdr. How would you suggest I improve upon my approach? What would be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would not use a new window but a modal dialog.  jQuery UI has a nice modal dialog that you could load using AJAX